# Test class with @Qualifier @Autowired value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, annotations

I'm testing a class that has `@Qualified @Autowired` value:

```
// class under test
class C1() {

    @Autowired
    @Qualified("c1")
    DataSource d1;
    ...
}
```

DataSource `d1` located in config file.

But when I'm testing same class and I'm using separate `DataSource` which is in test config class:

```
// test for class
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = testC1Config.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
class testC1() {

    @Autowired
    @Qualified("c1Test")
    DataSource d1Test;
    ...
}

// testC1Config
@Configuration
class testC1Config() {

    @Bean
    @Qualified("c1Test")
    DataSource c1Test() {
    ...
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=c1)}
```

says that he only sees DataSource Bean with only Qualifier `c1`. Have tried to use `@Bean(name=c1Test")` but I get same result..

How do I make him to see the c1Test DataSource bean in test package?

Comment: @user7294900 my bad, I have ```@Qualifier``` in my testConfig file for this method. It still says that he only sees ```c1```

Comment: On the bean definition try `@Bean(name = "c1Test")` instead of `@Qualified("c1Test")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I made a work-arround that works.

(Behind the scenes) For my case I have 2 DataSources in test and src packages, when I'm testing the method in src, he has `@Autowired` DataSource and he asks to use the bean that is qualified with `c1`, but since I didnt had `c1` DataSource in my `testC1Config()` I got this exception.

So instead autowiring a bean and using qualifier with specific name, I wrote the autowired **setter** with qualifier containing same name in src config bean.

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("c1")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

For my case I'm constructing 2 jdbcTemplates too, this way whenever I run test Bean injects the DataSource I need and do stuff for me before `@Test`. If doing this way, no bean names required in config, but in services `@Qualifier("with_same_name_in_src_and_test")`.

Don't know if it's a good approach to this problem, but.... it works.